# How to present UIViewController as partial view?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, modalviewcontroller

For example, the Music app's "now playing" screen and the Mail app's email composition screen as shown below:

[image: modal example screenshot] [image: modal example screenshot]

How do I present my views like that? I'm assuming it can't be achieved purely using storyboards alone as all options seem to cover the full screen and not the partial modals as required.

Comment: You can try to change background colour to clear (so you will be able to see viewController which is below) and add another view(smaller than the main view) and set its colour to white. :) Just my idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not the most recent question, so I put this for future use. Hopefully you already made it.

First all you need to do is follow [this UIPresentationController guide](https://www.raywenderlich.com/139277/uipresentationcontroller-tutorial-getting-started) as is.

Then adjust the *presented* view controller frame to larger than 2/3 of the screen.

```
override func containerViewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    presentedView?.frame = frameOfPresentedViewInContainerView
    presentedView?.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
    presentedView?.layer.masksToBounds = true
}

override func size(forChildContentContainer container: UIContentContainer,
                   withParentContainerSize parentSize: CGSize) -> CGSize {
    switch direction {
        case .left, .right:
            return CGSize(width: parentSize.width*(2.0/3.0), height: parentSize.height)
        case .bottom, .top:
            return CGSize(width: parentSize.width, height: parentSize.height-40.0)
    }
}

override var frameOfPresentedViewInContainerView: CGRect {
    var frame: CGRect = .zero
    frame.size = size(forChildContentContainer: presentedViewController,
                withParentContainerSize: containerView!.bounds.size)

    switch direction {
        case .right:
            frame.origin.x = containerView!.frame.width*(1.0/3.0)
        case .bottom:
            frame.origin.y = 40.0
        default:
            frame.origin = .zero
    }
    return frame
}
```

Then set the *presenting* view controller frame during the dimming animation.

```
    self.presentingFrame = self.presentingViewController.view.frame
    var frame = self.presentingFrame
    frame.size.width -= 40.0
    frame.size.height -= 60.0
    frame.origin.x += 20.0
    frame.origin.y += 30.0

    coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: { _ in
        self.dimmingView.alpha = 1.0

        self.presentingViewController.view.frame = frame

        self.presentingViewController.view.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
        self.presentingViewController.view.layer.masksToBounds = true

        UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
    })
```

Don't forget to add the reverse animation too. Result:

[image: result!]

Answer (score 2):

> I'm assuming it can't be achieve purely on storyboards alone...

- Yes, it can't be.
   
  Evaluate implementing [Custom View Controller Transition Animation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/PresentingaViewController.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH14-SW1) to get the transitions right & thereupon it should just be `frame & alpha` manipulations on the presented view controller's subviews.